# webview Header Access

Tags: android, android-webview

I use Webview to load an url using loadUrl(url), is there any way to get headers in Webview? Can we customize the header? Can anyone show me the code? Thanks.

Comment: You mean to show editable address bar?

Comment: headers usually content info about User Agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android 2.2 and higher there is another [loadUrl method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29)
with custom header information.
I haven't used it yet...